# Control which form will load first in vb.net by coding

Tags: vb.net

Is there a way to control which form will load first when the program starts in vb.net programmatically? Like a main method or something like that?

Comment: In Visual Studio: Project-->Properties-->Application-->Startup Object. Or using code, basic googling will help : https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms235406.aspx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, this is possible.

Add a public Main somewhere. (For example in a new class)

```
Public Shared Sub Main()
    'Create and show your form here
End Sub
```

Then in the application settings, disable "Enable application framework" and select the Main method as the startup object.